# How to select only the "parent" div of an image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am trying to make a div change background color when an image beneath the div is rolled over as well as when the div itself is rolled over.

So far I am able to get the div change colors on rollover but when I have more than 1 image on the page rolling over the image changes the background color of all the other divs as well

I might not be writing this the most understandable way.. But the code and fiddle should help

Html:

```
<a href="test.html">
      <div style ="width:233px; float:left; position:relative; margin-right:17px; margin-bottom:20px;  ">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:213px; height:20px;  display:block; float:left; color:#fff; padding:10px; background-color: #000; opacity:0.8; "  class="cat_top_bar" >image name </div>
          <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" width="233" height="233" class="img_cat"  >  
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="test.html">
      <div style ="width:233px; float:left; position:relative; margin-right:17px; margin-bottom:20px;  ">
        <div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:213px; height:20px;  display:block; float:left; color:#fff; padding:10px; background-color: #000; opacity:0.8; "  class="cat_top_bar" >image name </div>
          <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" width="233" height="233" class="img_cat"  >  
      </div>
    </a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".cat_top_bar").hover(function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
                        opacity: 0.98
                    }, 100);
                },

                function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    },100);
                });

                $(".img_cat").hover(function () {
                    $(".cat_top_bar").animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
                        opacity: 0.98
                    }, 100)
                },

                function () {
                    $(".cat_top_bar").animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    },100);
                });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ffB8k/

I think this is more of a css question than anything as I am not sure how I can select the parent div.. Which is not really parent, just before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way by using [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) :

```
$(".img_cat").hover(function () {
                    $(this).prev(".cat_top_bar").animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
                        opacity: 0.98
                    }, 100)
                },

                function () {
                    $(this).prev(".cat_top_bar").animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    },100);
                });
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffB8k/2/)

Comment: Ah nice! Did not know about .prev

Answer (score 2):

In a jQuery event handler, `this` is the target of the event. From there, you can use jQuery [traversal functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find related elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vGNM/

```
$(".img_cat").hover(function () {
    $(this).siblings(".cat_top_bar").animate({
        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
        opacity: 0.98
    }, 100)
},

function () {
    $(this).siblings(".cat_top_bar").animate({
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.8
    }, 100);
});
```

`$(this).prev('.cat_top_bar')` would also work, as would `$(this).parent().find('.cat_top_bar')`. There are lots of ways to traverse the DOM, but the key is starting with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the *parent*-div (which is not actually a parent, but a sibling), you can use jQuery's [prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 0):

If moving the cursor from `img` to `.cat_top_bar` and vice versa doesn't have to trigger the background animation you could also attach the `hover` handler to the parent, so you won't have to duplicate the animation code. http://jsfiddle.net/ffB8k/3/

```
$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.cat_top_bar').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
        opacity: 0.98
    }, 100);
},

function () {
    $(this).find('.cat_top_bar').animate({
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        opacity: 0.8
    },100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cat_top_bar").hover(function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
                        opacity: 0.98,
                    }, 100).css({"z-index":"12"});
                },

                function () {
                    $(this).animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    },100);
                });

                $(".img_cat").hover(function () {

                    $(this).parent().children().animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#f49000',
                        opacity: 0.98
                    }, 100).css({"z-index":"12"});
                },

                function () {
                    $(".cat_top_bar").animate({
                        backgroundColor: '#000',
                        opacity: 0.8
                    },100);
                });
```

Use z-index and parent() and children()